# Qt static build missing windows plugin

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I've compiled Qt 5.9.3 to static library using

```
configure -static -release -platform win32-msvc
```

I'm compiling my application and it compiles and links successfully but when I start it it fails with

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows"

The problem is clearly that it fails to find the qwindows plugin which is now a .lib and not a .dll
I tried adding qwindows.lib to the linker input files but that did not have any effect.
Is there a known fix for this issue?

Comment: I've had problem like that too. Some plugins are loaded dynamically from the plugin directory. By any chance: 

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-plugins.html#the-plugin-directory

Try to put the appropriate dll/lib/whatever in the plugin directory. I hope this helps you.

Comment: @user2346536 the whole point of having a static build is that I won't need outside dlls from the plugins directory

Answer (score 0):

May be you linked another Qt lib. If so, your application will require windows plugin.
Use tools like dependcy walker http://dependencywalker.com/ find out what dll your application depends on.
Tips: I used to installed anaconda, and build qt from source, my application linked qt lib of anaconda, so it require windows plugin and never find the dll.